# When clicked on a button that handles event more than one time setInterval goes crazy?

Tags: javascript, html, button, setinterval

When I click in the automatic button (auto) more than once, which handles the setInterval method, the color Divs go crazy fast, now the reason is what I'm here for to know. This is the DEMO in jsfiddle[DEMO OF COLOR DIVS WITH SETINTERVAL METHOD](http://jsfiddle.net/jobson111/q32kG/)

Body:

```
<div id="placeDiv1">ok</div>
<button id="b1" onclick="forward()">Forward</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="backward()">Backward</button>
<button id="b3" onclick="skip2()">skip2</button>
<button id="b4" onclick="automatic()">auto</button>
<button id="b5" onclick="stop()">stop</button>
<script>
    var myArray = ["black", "yellow", "green", "red", "blue", "blue", "black", "gray"];
    var myArray1 = ["yellow", "blue", "green", "red", "green", "blue", "black", "gray"];
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
    document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
    forward = function () {

        if (i == myArray.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
        document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
    };
    skip2 = function () {

        if (i == myArray.length - 4) {
            i += 2;
            alert("This is the iterator " + i)
        } else if (i == 7) {
            i = 0
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        };
        document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
        document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
    };
    backward = function () {

        if (i == 0) {
            i = myArray.length - 1;
            i = myArray1.length - 1;
        } else {
            i = i - 1;
        }

        document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
        document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
        //

    }
    automatic = function () {
        var m = setInterval(function () {
            if (i == myArray.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
            document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
        }, 100);
        stop = function () {
            clearInterval(m)
        };
    };
</script>
```

CSS:

```css
#placeDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#placeDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#b1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px
}
#b2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 80px
}
#b3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 170px
}
#b4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 270px
}
#b5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 320px
}
```

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/q32kG/1/

Comment: This is shortest cut for what I need. I think it helped alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the script like

```
  var m=null;   
  automatic=function(){
   clearInterval(m);
   m = setInterval(function(){
     if(i == myArray.length-1) 
         {i=0;}
         else
         {i=i+1;}
         document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
       document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
  },100);

 stop=function(){
    clearInterval(m);
 };
```

Check **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q32kG/1/)**

You need to Kill the setinterval when you call the function `automatic` and also need to define `var m` outside the function

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding your code a bit confusing, but the way i see it, you are setting the interval multiple times. Each time you click the button, it creates another timer.

What you can do is set a variable to check if the timer is running, like so:

`var running = false;`

In your `automatic()` function, set `running` to `true`; and in `stop()`, set `running` to `false`.

Also in `automatic()`, only create the timer if it's not already running.

All together, we now have:

```
running = false;
automatic=function(){
if (!running) {
  running = true;
 var m = setInterval(function(){if(i == myArray.length-1) 
     {i=0;}
     else
     {i=i+1;}
     document.getElementById("placeDiv1").style.backgroundColor = myArray1[i];
   document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];},100);   
}     
     stop=function(){
clearInterval(m);
running = false};
```

Is it just me, or are you not closing the function properly as well?

Comment: I tried your code and it did not work, but the concepts is understable .